# TYPO3 - How to configure realurl when using f:widget.paginate

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x, realurl

I'm using f:widget.paginate in the list view of my extbase extension. I'm getting the following links when hovering over the paginate buttons:

```
/lei/?tx_lei_lei[%widget_0][currentPage]=2&cHash=7c2803c851b3a77d346456e319b5b81
```

... or when I click on the 2nd button in the browser I get:

```
/lei/?tx_lei_lei[%40widget_0][currentPage]=2&cHash=7c2803c45b3a77d87456459e319b5b81
```

What are the proper realurl configuration I can use to make the url pretty?

Edit:

```
'postVarSets' => array(
    '_DEFAULT' => array(
            'page' => array(
                    array(
                            'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[@widget_0][currentPage]',
                    ),
                    array(
                            'GETvar' => 'tx_lei_lei[@widget_0][currentPage]',
                    ),                                
            )                               
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
...
'postVarSets' => array(
                '_DEFAULT' => array(
                        'page' => array(
                                array(
                                        'GETvar' => 'tx_lei_lei[@widget_0][currentPage]',
                                ),
                        ),
                ),
),
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. The links look like this now: /lei/page//2/   How can I get rid of the additional / ? In the docs https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/wiki/Configuration-reference#emptysegmentvalue I read sth about emptysegmentvalue option ... but it's not recommended to be used?!

Comment: I guess your additional ``/`` comes from another configuration and not the Paginate config.